# Rewrite all URLs to http://domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, google-ranking

1) Is it possible with *.htaccess* to rewrite all of your URLs to just `http://example.com`?

E.g.:

- `http://example.com/folder/subfolder/file.php` -> `http://example.com`
- `http://example.com/index.php` -> `http://example.com`
- `http://example.com/folder/file.php?foo=bar&baz=qux` -> `http://example.com`

2) If it is possible, how would this effect SEO and page rankings?

Comment: Note that users typically find this very annoying, as they are redirected to a new website with no hint as to how to find the information they were originally looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes possible, try this rule:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule . /? [L,R=302]
   ```
2. Since rule is not using `301` SEO may not be impacted.